# Deserializing simple string

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net

I'm sure I am missing something very obvious, and I've read different threads (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924316/json-net-deserialize-error) one, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860101/json-net-deserialization) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708606/json-net-deserialize-returning-nulls), just to name the last ones) but I still cannot find the answer...

Here are my classes:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebAPIClient
{
  public class XWTournament
  {
    private string name;

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
  }

  public class Root 
  {
    public XWTournament xwtournam { get => xwtournam; set => xwtournam = value; }
  }
}
```

And here I try to use them:

```
msg = "{\"tournament\": {\"Name\": \"Worlds 2014 Flight One\"}}";

Root root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(msg) ;
string pippo = root.xwtournam.Name;
```

But in this case I am receiving a stack overflow error...

What am I missing? How can I read the variables in the string?

*Edit*: thanks to the useful answers, I have corrected the code in this way

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebAPIClient
{
    public class XWTournament
    {
        //I've deleted the private variable
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public class Root 
    {
        [JsonProperty("tournament")]
        public XWTournament xwtournam { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you use my code you can solve your problem

Comment: You should not define getters/setters if there's no real functionality there. As you have it, `{ get; set; }` would do exactly the same, and you wouldn't need private fields then.

Comment: @AmirHKH sorry, where is your code?

Comment: @jeff-skyrunner I posted it below, please use that and if you have any questions, i can explain it more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None of your classes have a property named `tournament`. Your JSON does. What does that suggest?

```
public class Root 
{
    public XWTournament tournament { get; set; }
}
```

You also don't need the infinite recursion in the setter as you wrote it. Try assigning to it: The getter and the setter both just call themselves. That's the cause of the stack overflow exception. You'd get one if you tried to set that property, too.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me very much